# Hacking Checkbox Values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm writing a website app to allow the user to pick toppings for their pizza using checkboxes. Each checkbox is assigned a name for their value attribute, for example:

```
<li name="meatItem" id="m1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem" id="Pep" value="1.5">Pepperoni</li>
```

I am going to write a php script that loops through all of the checkboxes and determines a price for the pizza by adding all of the values from each checkbox. But I'm worried about the HTML being hacked to change the value attributes, which would obviously cause my php pricing script to be inaccurate. Is this a valid concern? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Then don't store the prices on the front end. On the back end pepperoni = x.

Comment: Yes, what @relentless said, just make a variable like `$pep = 1.5` and then for each one, add that value to the current total

Comment: Yes, have the value as "y" or "1" meaning "on", and change `name="checkItem"` to match your `id`, i.e. set it to `Pep`. You can then receive this value on the server side, and convert it to a price there.

Comment: p.s. that's not hacking...

Comment: You can actually leave the price in the front end if you need it for quick totals and such. * But *, when they place the order recalculate the total server-side. You're right to worry about front end prices, so although you can use them for display purposes, don't rely on them for final checkout totals.

Comment: I'd love to order a pizza from you. Just about anyone with a browser can modify client side code. Don't trust HTML, Javascript or jQuery for anything like that, only use html forms to get variable data from your user, not important data for your scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather then having the price values directly in the checkbox HTML, you should have the checkbox value be a "code" instead, that maps to whatever topping they want. Like 1=cheese, 2=peppers, etc. Then on the backend, have the code=>price mapping, and calculate the price + what toppings are needed in the PHP, based on what codes were given. Or else, as you say, it is quite possible for someone to hack these values.

Comment: If you use codes, it is still possible for people to change the values of one slightly more expensive code such as pepperoni's to a cheaper code such as that for cheese. (If there are any price differences between ingredients.)

Comment: This is true, but then the php script would just see that they had ordered cheese, and they'd end up with the wrong pizza. Or maybe they change the code for pepperoni to cheese as well as selecting cheese, then they have 2 orders for cheese... Basically they CAN still change the value but it's not going to help them any.

Comment: all changing the codes would do would change the order, not get you a cheaper pizza

Comment: @Dagon well that's not NECESSARILY true, it could get you a cheaper pizza (a topping costing 1.0 is cheaper then one costing 1.5). But you wouldn't be getting a more expensive pizza for a cheaper price, which is the more important thing to prevent.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  If the code is the "value" being passed and the "name" does not matter, then it would work.  I was thinking you were using the "name" to get the ingredient and the "value" to pass a code and get a, well, a value.

Comment: Well if you're using a code to get the value, it doesn't actually make sense to also be passing the name of the topping, since you can easily figure it out based on the code passed. I guess you could use them both to put in some sort of "hah you were trying to hack!" message if you wanted to.

Comment: Or just `if(id = chicken){ price = 2 }`

Comment: That's true, the ID certainly doesn't have to be numeric. It could even be the name of the topping, as long as the price is still calculated back-end. Though considering that you're not using any quotes in that code, perhaps `chicken` is just a variable that = the id of the chicken topping? ;) (actually on second glance that if statement isn't even a valid comparison, due to the single equals sign)

Comment: I thought that might be a problem as well, but Bucky24 changed my mind.  If you don't even consider the "name" fields (other than to get the code values) then you don't need to worry about that.  As long as the code matches the ingredient in the back-end, then it will also match the price for said ingredient.  That way you don't have to worry about "hackers" trying to get free (or cheaper) food.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you everyone for your quick (and ABUNDANT) responses!! :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, don't ever trust anything a user can enter, ever.

Yes, someone can change those values quite easily, in fact they could submit their own form to your page with whatever values etc they want.

You would be better taking the submitted data (ie POST/GET) and first checking the names and data is what it should be (ie `strlen()`, regex for A-z0-9, possibly an array with all valid data,  etc) and then once you are happy all data submitted is valid, then get your prices from a database/other source based on the form names.

Simply posting them with the form, someone will change the prices to 0.00 and get it for free. As such, it's pointless posting prices in the form when you will have to check them from your own source anyway (mysql etc).